# Copying data from 1D array to 2D array using pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm practicing pointers and still confused on how to manipulate 2d arrays with pointer operations.
I want to be able to copy oneDim into twoDim using pointers. How does this work ?

```
int main() {

    char oneDim[] = "string of tests";
    char twoDim[2][8]; 
    char *pOne, *pTwo;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @yan How do you want the content of the two-dimensional array would look?

Comment: What do you mean? The letters are stored in a 2x8 matrix technically, right?

Comment: do you want to put the first 8 chars of oneDim into the first array of twoDim and the rest into the second?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Do you want null-terminated strings in `twoDim[0]` and `twoDim[1]`?  If so, you've undersized the `twoDim` array.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you are going to copy the one-dimensional array in the two-dimensional array. One approach is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char oneDim[] = "string of tests";
    char twoDim[2][8]; 
    char *pOne, *pTwo;

    pOne = oneDim;
    pTwo = twoDim[0];

    memcpy( pTwo, pOne, sizeof( twoDim[0] ) - 1 );
    pTwo[sizeof( twoDim[0] ) - 1] = '\0';

    pTwo = twoDim[1];
    pOne += sizeof( twoDim[0] ) - 1;

    strncpy( pTwo, pOne, sizeof( twoDim[1] ) - 1);
    pTwo[sizeof( twoDim[1] ) - 1] = '\0';

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", twoDim[0] );
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", twoDim[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
"string "
"of test"
```

Take into account that word "tests" was not copied entirely because there is not enough characters in the two-dimensional array when this approach is used.

The other approach is straightforward.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char oneDim[] = "string of tests";
    char twoDim[2][8]; 
    char *pOne, *pTwo;

    pOne = oneDim;
    pTwo = twoDim[0];

    strcpy( pTwo, pOne );

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", pTwo );
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
"string of tests"
```

If you may not use standard C string functions then for example call

```
    memcpy( pTwo, pOne, sizeof( twoDim[0] ) - 1 );
```

can be substituted for loop

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( twoDim[0] ) - 1; i++ ) pTwo[i] = pOne[i];
```

Or your could write

```
while ( pTwo < twoDim[0] + sizeof( twoDim[0] ) - 1 ) *pTwo++ = *pOne++;
*pTwo = '\0';
```

In this case statement

```
    pOne += sizeof( twoDim[0] ) - 1;
```

has to be deleted.

Comment: I cannot use strcpy or memcpy

Comment: @ryan You may substitute them for ordinary loops.

Comment: the second method is very dangerous, writing more than 8 characters to `pTwo` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch  There is neither undefined behaviour.

Comment: writing to `pTwo[8]` is undefined behaviour. `twoDim[0][8]` is not necessary the same as `twoDim[1][0]`.

Comment: @mch You are wrong. It is the same for two-dimensional arrays.